# How to pass a chained method as an argument for another method in the same class?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with a bunch of chained methods. Here is an example:

```
class Sum {
    public static $res = [];
    private static $instance = null;

    public static function run() {
        if (self::$instance === null)
            self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function res() {
        return self::$res;
    }

    public function addTen($int) {
        self::$res = $this->addFour($str) + 6;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addFour($int) {
        self::$res = $int + 4;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

So if I want to call the addTen() method I can do like so:

```
echo Sum::run()->addFour(5)->res(); // Works, returns 9
echo Sum::run()->addTen(5)->res(); // Doesn't work
```

The above code doesn't work because the chained methods return the current object from the Sum class. So I managed to fix this by changing the addTen() method so it calls the res() method after the addFour() method like so:

```
public function addTen($int) {
    self::$res = $this->addFour($str)->res() + 6;
    return $this;
}
```

In the above case, that is ok because there is only on method being called from inside the addTen() method but what if I need to call a lot of other chained methods from inside the addTen() method? How can I do so the res() method is no longer needed to be called after every single call from another chained method inside the class (it could become unhandable to have a lot of "->res()" being called everywhere in the class).

Comment: And `$this->bar` is defined where and how exactly in the example? What type of class is it? Is this a general example or does it only contain calculations with numbers?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just edited the above code. `$this->bar` should be `$this->addFour`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is your task for this class, but manually writing "add" per function will not make your class adaptable. As I have noted, you have used an array and not chain the $res properly. Since this is a sum class I would expect that you want to sum up the chain.

so I rewrote your class:

```
<?php

class Sum {
    public static $res = [];
    private static $instance = null;

    public static function run() {
        if (self::$instance === null)
            self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function res() {
        return array_sum(self::$res);
    }

    public function add($int) {
        self::$res[] = $int;
        return $this;
    }

}
$sum = new Sum();
$x = $sum->add(5)->add(6)->res();
echo $x; // 11
```

and you can see it work here:
https://3v4l.org/itDHN

Comment: Would have written an equivalent answer, makes more sense what the purpose of class `Sum` is. Though giving `Sum` a static member means that any instance of `Sum` will always share the same property/value. E.g. `(new Sum())->add(5); (new Sum())->res();` will produce `5` and not `0` as might usually be expected. It may be that the OP isn't aware of this.

Comment: @dbf agreed. its a singleton at this point. two options - they would exit or create a function to reset the array back to zero.

Comment: Well, `Singleton` is a good point, but in your rewrite you are not using the `run()` method to instantiate (share the instance of) `Sum` and second, `Sum` does not contain a private or protected `constructor` to be used in a `Singleton` construct. My comment was solely based on `static` behavior in general concerning the property `public static $res` where this property will be **literally** shared among all instances of `Sum` (assigned to the class `Sum`), not in a `Singleton` construct, where each call will **share** the same instance of `Sum`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this doesn't answer the question anyway. The main point of this question is: how can I do so the `res()` method may be avoided when calling the `addFour()` inside another method in the same class.

Comment: @rpbramos wait your requirement and your question aren't following now. you want to avoid the res method now? Your example and what you want doesnt make sense

Comment: @azngunit81 quoting the last paragraph of the question: _How can I do so the res() method is no longer needed to be called after every single call from another chained method inside the class?_. If I need to call a method that returns `$this`, I will have to do this way: `addFour(3)->res()`. I want to call the `addFour()` without the need of calling the `res()` (assuming I am calling `addFour()` from inside the `addTen()` method.

Comment: Only problem with this answer besides the $res being static is that the add method doesn't return a new instance, it returns the same, so: `$step = $sum->add(5); $sum->res(); $step->res();` both `$sum->res()` and `$step->res()` point to the same instance giving you `x+5` instead of `x+5` and `x`